# wordpress custom post type loop by tag id

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages

I'm trying to make a loop of a custom type of posts by tag ID.
This is the original code:

```html
<?php $args = array(
            'post_type' => 'kana_portfolio',
            'meta_key'   => 'choose_layout_2',
            'meta_value' => 'layout-1',
            'posts_per_page' => -1
        );
        $posts = get_posts($args);
        $term_array = array();
        $portfolio_term_array = array();
        foreach ( $posts as $post ) : setup_postdata( $post );
            $terms = wp_get_post_terms( get_the_ID(), 'kana_genre');
            foreach($terms as $term){
                $term_array[$term->slug] = $term->name;
                $portfolio_term_array[] = $term->slug;
            }
        endforeach;
        wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
```

Since I need to loop only the posts in a certain category (of custom posts type) having id 31 I added "'tag_id' => 31" after "'posts_per_page' => -1"

```html
<?php $args = array(
            'post_type' => 'kana_portfolio',
            'meta_key'   => 'choose_layout_2',
            'meta_value' => 'layout-1',
            'posts_per_page' => -1,
            'tag_id' => 31
        );
        $posts = get_posts($args);
        $term_array = array();
        $portfolio_term_array = array();
        foreach ( $posts as $post ) : setup_postdata( $post );
            $terms = wp_get_post_terms( get_the_ID(), 'kana_genre');
            foreach($terms as $term){
                $term_array[$term->slug] = $term->name;
                $portfolio_term_array[] = $term->slug;
            }
        endforeach;
        wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
```

**[EDIT]**
I have another loop below in the page and I tried to insert 'cat'=>31 tax_query array

```html
                <?php $number_posts_to_display = get_field('number_of_posts_to_display');
                $display_order = get_field('post_display_order');
                $portfolio = array(
                    'post_type' => 'kana_portfolio',
                    'posts_per_page' => $number_posts_to_display,
                    'order' => $display_order,
                    'meta_key'   => 'choose_layout_2',
                    'meta_value' => 'layout-1',
                    'tax_query' => array(
                        array(
                            'taxonomy' => 'kana_genre',
                            'field'    => 'slug',
                            'terms'    => $portfolio_term_array,
                        ),
                    ),
                );
                $portfolio_loop = new WP_Query($portfolio); ?>
```

But nothing is showed, how can I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if your category (we are talking real categories here, of the taxonomy type category...) is 31, you should use 'cat'=>31, tags are tags, they are not categories.. if this helped, let me know. if you were trying to filter on tags and it was not working, let me know as well and ill take a look in depth.

Have fun!

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I changed "id" in "cat" but still not working.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of:

```
'tag_id' => 31
```

Try this:

```
'tag__in' => 31
```